# How Retrieve all the files and folders recursively in a specific folder using SPFX REST API post method

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, spfx

How Retrieve all the files and folders recursively in a specific folder using SPFx REST API post method?

```
private _spApi(): void {
    this.context.spHttpClient
      .post(`${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/Lists/GetByTitle('Title')/GetItems(query=@v1)?$expand=File&@v1={"ViewXml":"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='FileDirRef' /><Value Type='Text'>/Folder/Subfolder</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"}`,
        SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
        {
          headers: [
            ['accept', 'application/json;odata=nometadata'],
            ['odata-version', 'v4.0']
          ]
        })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(web => console.log("Web: ", web)).catch(error => console.log("Error: ",error));
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error while using above code?

Comment: I am checking to see how things are going there on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the base folder in there where clause of the CAML query, you should set it using the `FolderServerRelativeUrl` property of the query object.

```
private _spApi(): void {
  const siteUrl = this.context.pageContext.web.serverRelativeUrl;
  const options: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "query": {
        "ViewXml": "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'></View>",
        "FolderServerRelativeUrl": `${siteUrl}/Lists/Title/Folder/Subfolder`
      }
    })
  };

  const url = `${siteUrl}/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('Title')/GetItems?$select=*,FileDirRef`;
  this.context.spHttpClient
    .post(url, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, options)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(web => console.log("Web: ", web)).catch(error => console.log("Error: ",error));
}
```